# error loading discovery document - AD FS integration using angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, adfs, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am working on an angular SPA which is needed to be authenticated using AD FS. I am using Spring Boot as a backend.

```
this.oauthService.configure({
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/app/search',
      requireHttps: true,
      scope: 'openid profile email',
      responseType: 'id_token token',
      oidc: true,
      clientId: environment.adfsClientId,
      loginUrl: environment.adfsUrl + '/oauth2/authorize',
      issuer: environment.adfsUrl,
      logoutUrl:
        environment.adfsUrl +
        '/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=' +
        location.protocol +
        '//' +
        location.hostname +
        (location.port ? ':' + location.port : ''),
      postLogoutRedirectUri:
        location.protocol +
        '//' +
        location.hostname +
        (location.port ? ':' + location.port : ''),
    });
```

The above given is the configuration. And I am following [this](https://wiliammbr.com/access-adfs-secured-web-api-via-angular-spa/) as a reference.

But I am getting the below error.

> **error loading discovery document**
> O {headers: h, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://adfs_domain/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration", ok: false, …}
> error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
> headers: h {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
> message: "**Http failure response for https://adfs_domain/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration: 0 Unknown Error**"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 0
> statusText: "Unknown Error"
> url: "https://adfs_domain/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Note: I can access the same URL, https://adfs_domain/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration, from my browser. the issuer URL in the config and the response in the browser are the same too.

can anyone help?

Comment: Is your app running on https using a valid certificate? It might be that your ADFS rejects connection from unsecure referer.

Comment: The App is running on HTTPS. But I am not sure about the certificate. How to check it and where can I configure it?

Comment: I contacted the server admin and he said that in test and pre-prod environments self-signed SSL certificates are being used.

Answer (score 1):

That will be a CORS issue, where ADFS is not allowing a cross domain request to the discovery endpoint from your SPA's web origin.

- If the discovery endpoint works from the browser there are no problems with SSL certificates
- But accessing the discovery endpoint in the browser is not a cross domain request

See [item 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs) in this document. All Authorization Servers have options for enabling CORS for SPA clients though the option seems a little painful in ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me because of my application's HTTP_INTERCEPTORS.

- try removing the interceptor and test again
- use the correct version to oidc for your application

This worked for me.